# As CommonJS dies out, what should go in a library’s package.json "main" field?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, package.json, commonjs

When the maintainer of a JavaScript package decides to stop distributing a CommonJS version, what should go into the `"main"` field of the **package.json** file?

Example old **package.json** fields with the CommonJS file as the `"main"` entry:

```json
   "type": "module",
   "module": "dist/pretty-print-json.js",
   "browser": "dist/pretty-print-json.min.js",
   "main": "dist/pretty-print-json.umd.cjs",
   "types": "dist/pretty-print-json.d.ts",
   "files": ["dist"],
   "exports": {
      ".": {
         "import": "./dist/pretty-print-json.js",
         "require": "./dist/pretty-print-json.umd.cjs"
      },
      "./": "./dist/"
   },
```

Example new **package.json** fields:

```json
   "type": "module",
   "module": "dist/pretty-print-json.js",
   "browser": "dist/pretty-print-json.min.js",
   "main": “???????????”,
   "types": "dist/pretty-print-json.d.ts",
   "files": ["dist"],
   "exports": "./dist/pretty-print-json.js",
```

The [**node** documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/packages.html#main) states:

> The `"main"` field defines the entry point of a package when imported by name via a `node_modules` lookup.  Its value is a path.  When a package has an `"exports"` field, this will take precedence over the `"main"` field when importing the package by name.

**node** will use `"exports"` over `"main"`, but the various bundlers out in the wild might implement different rules.  Should the `"main"` field simply be removed once a package drops support to `require()` a CommonJS module?

Comment: the documentation suggests if you have `exports` then don't use `main` since `exports` takes precedence - `the various bundlers out in the wild might implement different rules` then do what the *various bundlers* document needs to be done

Comment: note: I've seen `package.json`s in the wild with top level `"module"` property pointing to the same file as `exports` `"import"` property - if that helps - they also have `"main"` pointing to the same file as `exports` `"require"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `"main"` field and use `"exports"` instead.

An author of many prominent npm packages, [sindresorhus](https://www.npmjs.com/%7Esindresorhus), wrote an FAQ titled *["How can I move my CommonJS project to ESM?"](https://gist.github.com/sindresorhus/a39789f98801d908bbc7ff3ecc99d99c#how-can-i-move-my-commonjs-project-to-esm)* and recommended:

> Replace `"main": "index.js"` with `"exports": "./index.js"` in your package.json.

A quick survey of some of the popular packages I depend on shows lots of inconsistencies.  Some packages even set `"type": "module"` and point `"main"` to an ESM file.  The most important thing is to set `"exports"` correctly.